# Android answer list doesnt move to the next answerlist

Tags: android, button, arraylist

i have been having this problem in displaying 4 answers in buttons. The 8,9,3,1 does appear when the play class is running, but it does not move to next answer list (17,20,15,14 and so on) after a button has been pressed...

**Java**

```
public class play extends Activity  {

private Question currentQuestion;
private int currentQuestionIndex;
private ArrayList<Button> questionButton;
private TextView questionstextview;
private TextView questionnumber;
private TextView playerfeedback;
public static TextView displayscore;
public static int score;
private List<Question> QuestionList;
private int answerchoice; 
public static int totalanswer;
public static int correctanswer;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play);
        Log.i("playclass", "this is play class running");

        questionButton = new ArrayList<Button>();       
        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton1));
        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton2));
        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton3));
        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton4));
        currentQuestion = null;
        currentQuestionIndex = 0;

        QuestionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        ArrayList <String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();

        answer.add("8");
        answer.add("9");
        answer.add("3");
        answer.add("1");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 4+4", answer, 0));
        answer.add("17");
        answer.add("20");
        answer.add("15");
        answer.add("14");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 7+8?", answer, 3));
        answer.add("20");
        answer.add("30");
        answer.add("19");
        answer.add("34");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 10+10?", answer, 0));
        answer.add("12");
        answer.add("11");
        answer.add("13");
        answer.add("14");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 6+6?", answer, 0));
        answer.add("6");
        answer.add("5");
        answer.add("4");
        answer.add("7");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 4+3?", answer, 3));
        answer.add("7");
        answer.add("9");
        answer.add("10");
        answer.add("11");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 3+7?", answer, 2));

        questionstextview = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.questionstextview);           
        questionnumber = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.questionnumber);        
        displayscore = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.displayscore);

        StartTrivia();
    }
public void ButtonPress (View answerButton){

    MediaPlayer soundfx = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.click);

    soundfx.start();

    for (int i=0; i< questionButton.size(); i++)
    {   


        if (questionButton.get(i) ==answerButton)

        {   

         if (i==currentQuestion.getAnswerIndex())

          { 
             score=+5;
             totalanswer++;
             correctanswer++;

            displayscore.setText(Integer.toString(score));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        else{

            totalanswer++;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Log.i("playclass", "after incorrect toast");
        }

            currentQuestionIndex++;


             Log.i("playclass", "after currentQuestionIndex++; ");

            if (currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size()){

                Log.i("playclass", "after currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size() ");
                StartTrivia();
                Log.i("playclass", "after StartTrivia in if statement ");
            }

            else{

                Intent result = new Intent (this, finalscreen.class);
                startActivity(result);
                Log.i("playclass", "after IntentResult ");
            }
            break;
         }

    }   
}

public void StartTrivia(){

    Log.i("playclass", "running StartTrivia() " + currentQuestionIndex); 

    currentQuestion = QuestionList.get(currentQuestionIndex); 

    questionstextview.setText(currentQuestion.getquestion());

    questionnumber.setText(Integer.toString(currentQuestionIndex+1));

    for (int i = 0; i < questionButton.size(); i++)

     { 

         String ans = currentQuestion.getanswer().get(i); 
         questionButton.get(i).setText(ans);

     }

    }
```

}

**LogCat**

08-13 14:55:02.341: I/ActivityManager(73): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example.quizgame/.play } from pid 387
08-13 14:55:02.651: I/playclass(387): this is play class running
08-13 14:55:02.671: I/playclass(387): running StartTrivia() 0
08-13 14:55:03.422: I/ActivityManager(73): Displayed com.example.quizgame/.play: +1s2ms
08-13 14:55:05.634: D/dalvikvm(387): GC_CONCURRENT freed 92K, 3% free 9024K/9287K, paused 9ms+5ms
08-13 14:55:05.711: D/AudioSink(32): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
08-13 14:55:05.851: I/playclass(387): after currentQuestionIndex++; 
08-13 14:55:05.851: I/playclass(387): after currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size() 
08-13 14:55:05.861: I/playclass(387): running StartTrivia() 1
08-13 14:55:05.861: I/playclass(387): after StartTrivia in if statement 
08-13 14:55:08.712: D/AudioSink(32): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
08-13 14:55:08.745: I/playclass(387): after incorrect toast
08-13 14:55:08.745: I/playclass(387): after currentQuestionIndex++; 
08-13 14:55:08.752: I/playclass(387): after currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size() 
08-13 14:55:08.752: I/playclass(387): running StartTrivia() 2
08-13 14:55:08.775: I/playclass(387): after StartTrivia in if statement 
08-13 14:55:09.182: I/dalvikvm(73): Jit: resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048
08-13 14:55:10.102: D/AudioSink(32): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
08-13 14:55:10.162: I/playclass(387): after currentQuestionIndex++; 
08-13 14:55:10.162: I/playclass(387): after currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size() 
08-13 14:55:10.172: I/playclass(387): running StartTrivia() 3
08-13 14:55:10.231: I/playclass(387): after StartTrivia in if statement 
08-13 14:55:10.388: W/AudioFlinger(32): write blocked for 75 msecs, 1 delayed writes, thread 0xff38
08-13 14:55:11.911: D/AudioSink(32): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
08-13 14:55:12.011: I/playclass(387): after currentQuestionIndex++; 
08-13 14:55:12.011: I/playclass(387): after currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size() 
08-13 14:55:12.011: I/playclass(387): running StartTrivia() 4
08-13 14:55:12.011: I/playclass(387): after StartTrivia in if statement 
08-13 14:55:14.011: D/AudioSink(32): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
08-13 14:55:14.072: I/playclass(387): after incorrect toast
08-13 14:55:14.072: I/playclass(387): after currentQuestionIndex++; 
08-13 14:55:14.092: I/playclass(387): after currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size() 
08-13 14:55:14.092: I/playclass(387): running StartTrivia() 5
08-13 14:55:14.111: I/playclass(387): after StartTrivia in if statement 
08-13 14:55:17.691: D/AudioSink(32): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
08-13 14:55:17.761: I/playclass(387): after incorrect toast
08-13 14:55:17.761: I/playclass(387): after currentQuestionIndex++; 
08-13 14:55:17.822: I/ActivityManager(73): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example.quizgame/.finalscreen } from pid 387
08-13 14:55:17.876: I/playclass(387): after IntentResult 
08-13 14:55:18.112: W/AudioFlinger(32): write blocked for 76 msecs, 6 delayed writes, thread 0xff38
08-13 14:55:18.251: I/finalscreen(387): this is finalscreen class running
08-13 14:55:19.481: I/ActivityManager(73): Displayed com.example.quizgame/.finalscreen: +1s582ms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     ArrayList <String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
    answer.add("8");
    answer.add("9");
    answer.add("3");
    answer.add("1");
    QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 4+4", answer, 0));

    ArrayList <String> answer1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    answer1.add("17");
    answer1.add("20");
    answer1.add("15");
    answer1.add("14");
    QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 7+8?", answer1, 3));

   ArrayList <String> answer2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    answer2.add("20");
    answer2.add("30");
    answer2.add("19");
    answer2.add("34");
    QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 10+10?", answer2, 0));

    ArrayList <String> answer3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    answer3.add("12");
    answer3.add("11");
    answer3.add("13");
    answer3.add("14");
    QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 6+6?", answer3, 0));

    ArrayList <String> answer4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    answer4.add("6");
    answer4.add("5");
    answer4.add("4");
    answer4.add("7");
    QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 4+3?", answer4, 3));

   ArrayList <String> answer5 = new ArrayList<String>();
    answer5.add("7");
    answer5.add("9");
    answer5.add("10");
    answer5.add("11");
    QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 3+7?", answer5, 2));
```

Comment: Actually You are following wrong way use Map for better code.